# Is LIBOR a spot rate?

Tags: libor, spot-rate

Can we use USD LIBOR as spot rates for discounting?

If we have overnight LIBOR and say 1 month LIBOR how to compute 16 day LIBOR? Can we do interpolation?

Answer (score 3):

First question can't be answered without knowing what you are discounting.

Second question you are asking whether the rate of a 16 day interbank loan can be obtained from interpolating an overnight rate and a 1 month bank loan.  I would say it is a reasonable guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the first question - can i use 3 month libor for discounting cash flow receivable after 3 month.

Comment: It depends upon the riskiness of the cashflow.  If you are owed by a highly creditworthy source like a big bank, then 3 month libor is appropriate.  If the cashflow is from a risky investment , a higher rate would be appropriate.